# Laptop battery maintainence with proper guide

Tags: battery

How do I proper use my laptop battery??currently I am using windows 8 in my lenovo b590 model. I am confused with its power plan mode(balanced & power saver). In which options I
should go , whenever I am using my system in charging mode or in battery mode?? & please
write to me it's charging & discharging procedure.Thank You for your support as always.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to tell about battery use + there are different types of battery's.

Ing general: The first times you use the battery you should run on battery until it is almost empty then fully load it to 100%. That will improve your battery life. (the battery then remembers).

After that period just use it the way you would like to use your laptop either connected to the power cable or on battery.

After some years it might well be that your battery fails as one of the first components, then simply reorder a new battery.

Comment: Could you please tell me about the balanced mode & power saver mode?

Comment: if you choose "change plan settings" > "change advanced power settings" you get a whole list of choices. For each of these choices you can see what the differences are and you can customize them according to your liking.